# Display the current's user picture in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I used this measure to display a greeting message after retrieving the username of the session and the current timezone.

```
Greetings Deno = 
VAR v_LoginUserName = USERNAME() 
VAR v_hour = HOUR(UTCNOW()) 
VAR v_prefix = SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    v_hour < 12, " Good Morning ,",
    v_hour >= 12 && v_hour <= 17, "☀️ Good Afternoon ,",
    " Good Evening ,"
) 
RETURN v_prefix & " " & v_LoginUserName & " " & " ! "
```

I wanted to ask if it is possible to display the profile picture of the current logged-in user in an image viewer? Of course , if the user has no profile picture I'll display a default one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to display the profile picture of the current logged-in user in an image viewer by utilizing custom visuals or embedding external content in your report. However, it's important to keep in mind that Power BI doesn't have a built-in feature to directly fetch and display profile pictures based on the currently logged-in user.

You can create a separate table or data source that associates user names with their respective profile picture URLs or image file paths. You can keep it separate from your model.

Then retrieve the profile picture URL or file path associated with the currently logged-in user by querying the table you created already. You can use the USERNAME() function to get the logged-in user's name and perform a lookup or filter operation to retrieve the associated profile picture information.

You can use a custom visual or an embedded web content visual in Power BI to display the image.

If the user does not have a profile picture available, you can specify a default image URL or file path to display a default picture instead.

Comment: Copy-paste from ChatGPT